# Bokeh issue: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'hbar_stack'

Tags: python, bokeh

I am getting an `AttributeError` while trying to run the code
given on the gallery [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/bar_stacked_split.html)

My code:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import GnBu3, OrRd3
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("bar_stacked_split.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]

exports = {'fruits' : fruits,
           '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
           '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
           '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}
imports = {'fruits' : fruits,
           '2015'   : [-1, 0, -1, -3, -2, -1],
           '2016'   : [-2, -1, -3, -1, -2, -2],
           '2017'   : [-1, -2, -1, 0, -2, -2]}

p = figure(y_range=fruits, plot_height=350, x_range=(-16, 16), title="Fruit import/export, by year",
           toolbar_location=None)

p.hbar_stack(years, y='fruits', height=0.9, color=GnBu3, source=ColumnDataSource(exports),
             legend=["%s exports" % x for x in years])
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-ba2b732d27d9> in <module>()
      9            toolbar_location=None)
     10 
---> 11 p.hbar_stack(years, y='fruits', height=0.9, color=GnBu3, source=ColumnDataSource(exports),
     12              legend=["%s exports" % x for x in years])

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'hbar_stack'
```

Comment: Try updating bokeh version. It is working perfectly in version `0.12.14`.

Comment: I am using the current version 0.12.15. DO I have to use 0.12.14?

Comment: Running this on windows7 with bokeh 0.12.14 and am getting the same error..., python 3.6.5 32bit and bokeh installed via pip, so maybe there's some dependency problem...